# regarding javac

Tags: java, windows, command-line

javac is not internal or external command error is coming. I have set the path. then also it is giving the same error.

Comment: Downvoted for uninformative title and lack of specific error message from command line.  These two flaws make this question and its answers harder to find for other users experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you installed the JDK?

The JRE (aka "Java Runtime") does not contain javac, this is only part of the JDK ("Development Kit")

Answer (score 1):

You should first examine the `PATH` by executing this command:

```
echo %PATH%
```

Among these folders should be at least one that looks similar to this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin
```

Maybe you left out the `bin` at the end, maybe there isn't such a folder name at all in your `PATH`? We cannot know. If you tried this and are still unsure, post the value of the `PATH` so we can give you real tips instead of just guessing.

Comment: This is a confusing problem for newcomers since installing the JDK and JRE seems to put java.exe in a Registry-based command lookup instead of in the PATH. So while running java works from the command-line, running javac confusingly fails without manual configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, and running from a command prompt you need to reopen it to force any PATH changes to take effect